# SELECT everything but the SELECTION from a table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-delete

Having a table, structured like this:

| id | bar | foo | created_at | month_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 7/7/1999 | jan2020 |
| 2 | B | 20 | 7/7/1999 | jan2020 |
| 3 | C | 30 | 7/7/1999 | jan2020 |
| 4 | A | 40 | 7/7/1999 | jan2021 |
| 5 | A | 50 | 7/7/2000 | jan2021 |
| 6 | A | 60 | 7/7/2000 | feb2021 |

I used to run  a query like this one:

```
delete ns
from foo ns
inner join 
(
    select month_year, max(nsa.created_at) created_at
    from foo nsa 
    group by month_year
) 
ns1 on ns1.month_year = ns.month_year and ns1.created_at <> ns.created_at;
```

The idea of that query was that it used to delete the values that were `created_at` last, based on unique `month_year`. Anyway, it was working the way I wanted.

**The question:**

What I need - without deletion, to get the values that were not deleted from that query. Tried to replace `delete` with `select` and I only managed to get the values that I needed to delete (which makes a lot of sense, actually), but I want to get exactly the values, that I did not get from that query.

*(Feel free to edit the title to something making more sense in SQL)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a LEFT OUTER JOIN as follows

```
select ns.*
from foo ns
left outer join 
(
   select month_year, max(nsa.created_at) created_at
   from foo nsa 
   group by month_year
 ) 
ns1 on ns1.month_year = ns.month_year and ns1.created_at <> 
ns.created_at
where ns1.month_year IS NULL;
```

Comment: this looks like working from a first point of view, **but** it returns the columns `created_at` and `month_year` twice. The first pair is with a data and the second is with `NULL`. Any idea how to avoid this one? Another SELECT or something?

Comment: @Vityata, sorry I corrected the select clause.  Try it again now.